# how to avoid the error 42702 (AMBIGUOUS COLUMN ) with knex and postgres

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I have two tables, category and subcategory

both have the description field

I configured the following query

```
 const get = (req, res) => {
    app.db({ s: 'subCategory', c: 'category' })
        .select('s.id', 's.description', { category: 'c.description' })
        .whereRaw('?? = ??', ['c.id', 's.categoryId'])
        .where({ deletedAt: null })
        .then(subCategorys => res.json(subCategorys))
        .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err))
}
```

I renamed the category column description field,
but it presents the error of the duplicated column, I have another method that I rename in this way and it works however with those columns with the same name, it presents the error 42702 (that is the ambiguous error of the column)

I'm using postgresql and renamed knex to db

there is something to change in this method to make it work, or i will really need to create the whole query with knex.raw ?

error:  `{ "length": 111, "name": "error", "severity": "ERROR", "code": "42702", "position": "152", "file": "parse_relation.c", "line": "791", "routine": "colNameToVar" }`

Comment: Qualify all column names (like `deletedat`) with the table alias.

Comment: you were right, i added    `.whereNull('s.deletedAt')`  and it worked 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need define the columns ambiguous with alias.
if `deletedAt`is ambiguous on tables, you need set `s.deletedAt` in your query